# Python regexp replace 'a_1_1' to 'p.get("a_1_1", 0)'

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings in **python**, like:

```
1) 'a_1_2+c_2_4 + 5'
2) 'ctl_1_3/80'
3) 'd_10_55'
...
```

I want to replace them with **re**. They should look like:

```
1) 'p.get("a_1_2", 0)+p.get("c_2_4", 0) + 5'
2) 'p.get("ctl_1_3", 0)/80'
3) 'p.get("d_10_55", 0)'
```

Can you help me with regular expression?

P.S. **p** is simple dict in python

Comment: You want a parser, not a regex.

Comment: What's with the zero argument in the first line but not the other two?

Comment: to ThiefMaster: I thought that I have to search for this kind of strings before replace them.

Comment: You wanna replace each variable by p.get()? What is your naming rule of variables? They always start with a letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [7]: s = 'a_1_2+c_2_4 + 5'

In [8]: re.sub(r'(\w+_\d+_\d+)', r'p.get("\1", 0)', s)
Out[8]: 'p.get("a_1_2", 0)+p.get("c_2_4", 0) + 5'
```

It's unclear what rules govern the second argument to `p.get()`. It is present in the first example but not the other two.

Comment: Regex will work, but this code will not pass if I'm a code reviwer. :-) (see my post)

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko: I think your objection should be directed at the question, not the answer. Besides, I don't even see how the argument about double quotes etc even applies to `\w+_\d+_\d+`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to build JavaScript code using Python? What will happen if your string contains double quotes or any other JavaScript special characters?

While it certainly possible to a regex substitution I would suggest to pass data to client as JSON object (using Python's json library) and process that data on client side. That will result in cleaner and more supportable code.

Comment: p is simple dict in python. this string is for python eval.

Comment: Same thing applies to Python code. Just make sure that you are careful with sanitizing parameters passed to eval method.